# Is “My name is …” still used in introduction today?

Tags: american-english, greetings

I'm sure that most people use `I'm ...` when he or she introduces himself/herself. However, I also know that in old days people use `My name is ...` in the same situation. Is this phrase still used today? If that is the case, what kind of situations do people use it?

It seems that it is more often used in formal situations than otherwise, but what kind of formal situations do people use it?

Comment: Depends a lot on the context. I can't see one straight answer here.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46443/the-difference-between-i-am-and-my-name-is-in-a-face-to-face-meeting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're almost identical, though you're right in saying "*I'm...*" is used more often and is less formal. In general, if the other person has probably never heard of me before (e.g. a customer) I'd use "*My name is...*", and if I was being introduced to someone by a friend I'd use "*I'm...*" as my friend has probably mentioned my name before.

Comment: Also, if replying to  list of questions, e.g. "What is your name, address and driver's license number?" at an auto rental, I'd use "My name is..."

Comment: Thanks. When I send a business inquiry to a company's email, which one should I use? There is no section like *"Your name"* in the *"Contact us"* page.